# Remove uploaded files with filepond

Tags: flask, filepond

I really enjoy the **filepond** library and would like to implement it in my **flask** app. Since I was not able to find any useful examples online, I started to write my own, small, proof of concept web application. I would like to upload multiple images to the server and save the filenames in the database. Furthermore, I would like to edit an entry and add additional files or remove the existing ones.

So far I figured out how to **upload** and **revert** files before the form is submitted. I am also able to load existing files inside the edit form. Just when I click the *'x'* button on a loaded image inside the edit form the image is removed from the filepond window and a *'removefile'* event is fired, but the file still remains on the server. Is it possible to trigger the revert request on a loaded file or is there a better solution altogether?

[x-button does not remove the file from the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3wzD.png)

Here are the relevant snippets from my js file:

```
FilePond.registerPlugin(
    FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,
    FilePondPluginImagePreview,
    FilePondPluginFileRename,
    FilePondPluginFileValidateType
);

inputElement = document.querySelector(".filepond");
token = document
    .querySelector('input[name="csrf_token"]')
    .getAttribute("value");

FilePond.setOptions({
    server: {
        headers: { "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token },

        process: "./process",
        revert: "./revert",
        load: {
            url: "../",
        }
    },
});

const filepond = FilePond.create(inputElement, {
    //     Here I pass the files to my edit form in the following format:
    //
    //     files: [
    //         {
    //             source: 'static/images/some_name.png',
    //             options: {
    //                 type: 'local'
    //             }
    //         }]
});
```

The relevant code from .py file:

```
@app.route("/process", methods=["POST"])
@app.route("/edit/process", methods=["POST"])
def process():
    upload_dir = "static/images"
    file_names = []
    for key in request.files:
        file = request.files[key]
        picture_fn = file.filename
        file_names.append(picture_fn)
        picture_path = os.path.join(upload_dir, picture_fn)
        try:
            file.save(picture_path)
        except:
            print("save fail: " + picture_path)
    return json.dumps({"filename": [f for f in file_names]})


@app.route("/revert", methods=["DELETE"])
@app.route("/edit/revert", methods=["DELETE"])
def revert():
    upload_dir = "static/images"
    parsed = json.loads(request.data)
    picture_fn = parsed["filename"][0]
    picture_path = os.path.join(upload_dir, picture_fn)
    try:
        os.remove(picture_path)
    except:
        print("delete fail: " + picture_path)
    return json.dumps({"filename": picture_fn})
```

Here is the repository to my full flask-filepond app:
https://github.com/AugeJevgenij/flask_filepond

Please excuse me if the question is unclear, does not make sense or the code is written poorly.
I just started programming a few months ago.

Comment: Hi, you can add `remove` end point to the `server` property. https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/#remove it's not implemented by default because allowing users to remove files from the server seems to me a security risk.

Comment: Try to stick to the question as much as possible. Directly ask question with relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Acording to filepond [documentation](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/api/server/) you can remove a file stored locally on the server like this:

```
FilePond.setOptions({
  server: {
    remove: (source, load, error) {
      // 'source' is the path of the file and should be sent to a server endpoint via http
      

      // call the load method before ending the function
      load()
    }
  }
})
```

then on your server where you receive the source (path), use it to delete the file. Keep in mind that this is a risky approach to get your website hacked!